# Crop an image using a specific x, y coordinate in AppleScript

Tags: applescript

I was able to crop using the top - bottom padding and left - right padding, but how do we crop a specific region of interest from the image using AppleScript, like for example , if the total dimension of the original image is 1000*1000 , and I want the region from {200, 150 , 600 , 600 }

Comment: What tool are you using?  What have you done so far?

Comment: seeked from this link https://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/imageevents/07.html

Answer (score 2):

I do not believe it is possible to crop an arbitrary part out of an image with either **Image Events** or `sips` *"Scriptable Image Processing System"*.

If anyone knows different, kindly ping me and I am happy to stand corrected.

---

If you don't want to install any software on your Mac, you can achieve what you want with a small PHP script as it comes with **GD** installed to do the image processing. That will look something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/php -f

<?php
   $im = imagecreatefromjpeg("image.jpg");
   $crop_area = array('x'=>200,'y'=> 100,'width'=>600,'height'=>600);
   $result = imagecrop($im, $crop_area);
   imagejpeg($result,"result.jpg");
?>
```

Of course, you can put that in a script, say `"cropper.php"` and call it from **Applescript** with:

```
do shell script cropper.php
```

and you can also accept parameters so that you can pass in the name of the image, the crop geometry and the output filename.

---

Another option might be to install **ImageMagick** which you can do with **homebrew** by running:

```
brew install imagemagick
```

You can then use **ImageMagick** like this:

```
magick input.jpg -crop 600x600+200+150 result.jpg
```

You can call that from **Applescript** with:

```
do shell script "magick ..."
```

just the same as the PHP version above.